# How can I enable the built-in macOS theme known as Aqua on Windows XP?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, themes

I read on https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/25/21456525/microsoft-windows-xp-theme-mac-aqua that Windows has a "secret" macOS theme named Aqua that was discovered following the Windows XP's source code leak on 4chan on 2020-09-24.

How can I enable the built-in macOS theme on Windows XP?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I enable the built-in macOS theme on Windows XP?

I don't think you will be able to as the theme is **incomplete** and **marked for internal use only** as the article you linked to **clearly states**:

> One is labeled “Candy” and includes a design that closely resembles Apple’s Aqua interface that was first introduced at the Macworld Conference & Expo in 2000. Although **the theme is incomplete**, the Windows XP Start button and various buttons and UI elements are clearly themed to match Apple’s Aqua.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

And

> **Microsoft never released its Aqua theme for Windows XP** ... The theme itself is described as a “Whistler skin with eye candy,” and marked as **“for internal use only.”**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

"Internal use only" implies that the supporting code was never pushed into the released versions.

[Microsoft had a secret Windows XP theme that made it look like a Mac - The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/25/21456525/microsoft-windows-xp-theme-mac-aqua)

If you really want to use an "Aqua" theme for Windows XP, there is a free one [here](https://www.softpaz.com/themes/download-aqua-windows-xp-theme-93.htm):

> [image]